# concatenating/distributing between lists and tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

i have the following example.

```
prefix = ['blue ','brown ']
suffix = [('dog','shoes','bike'), ('tree','cat','car')]
```

i would like to obtain a new list that looks like this:

```
[('blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike'),
 ('blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car'),
 ('brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike'),
 ('brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car')]
```

that is, i want to distribute and concatenate each element of the first list with each item in each tuple in the second list. the second list can have more than 2 tuples, but each tuple will always have exactly 3 items.

any way to do this without having to write nested for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
lst = [tuple(i+x for x in j) for i in prefix for j in suffix]
print(lst)
# [('blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike'), 
# ('blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car'), 
# ('brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike'), 
# ('brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car')]
```

---

You can unwrap the comprehension into a for loop to understand better how it all works:

```
lst = []
for i in prefix:
   for j in suffix:
      lst.append(tuple(i+x for x in j))
```

Comment: this looks great - im trying to understand this intuitively and how to read it left to right or right to left. do you have the equivalent for loop construction?

Comment: @laszlopanaflex Updated!

Comment: thanks- this is where i struggle a bit to understand how python interprets these nested statements - other examples suggest left to right, which in this case i would have expected there to be an issue as "j" is not defined as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any way of getting four separate tupels without nesting (explicit or otherwise).

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will combine the lists.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for thing in suffix:
    print(list(map(''.join, product(prefix, thing))))


['blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike', 'brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike']
['blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car', 'brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car']
>>>
```

---

This looks interesting:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(product(prefix, suffix)))
[('blue ', ('dog', 'shoes', 'bike')),
 ('blue ', ('tree', 'cat', 'car')),
 ('brown ', ('dog', 'shoes', 'bike')),
 ('brown ', ('tree', 'cat', 'car'))]
```

Then map a function to the product of prefix and suffix.

```
>>> def f(t):
    p, s = t
    t = product([p], s)
    return map(''.join, t)

>>> z = product(prefix, suffix)
>>> y = map(f, z)
>>> 
>>> pprint(list(map(tuple, y)))
[('blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike'),
 ('blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car'),
 ('brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike'),
 ('brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car')]
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> x = [tuple(thing) for thing in y]
```

---

Or without `map`

```
>>> def f(t):
    p, s = t
    t = product([p], s)
    return tuple(''.join(thing) for thing in t)

>>> z = product(prefix, suffix)
>>> y = [f(thing) for thing in z]
>>> pprint(y)
[('blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike'),
 ('blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car'),
 ('brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike'),
 ('brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Numpy Broadcasting:**

Here's a fully vectorized implementation that does not use any loops. This function works for any size of a prefix/suffix input.

```
import numpy as np

def foo(prefix, suffix):

    '''
    input:
        prefix - list
        suffix - list of tuples

    output:
        numpy array
    '''

    # Converting the inputs to numpy arrays
    prefix = np.asarray(prefix)
    suffix = np.asarray(suffix)

    # Number of prefixes; to be used later
    numOfPrefixes = prefix.shape[0]
    # size of a suffix tuple size; to be used later
    tupleSize = suffix.shape[0]


    # Repeating the each prefix element "size of a suffix tuple size" times
    prefix = np.repeat(prefix, tupleSize)
    # Adding a new axis so that broadcasting is possible
    prefix = prefix[:, np.newaxis]

    # Repeating the original list of tuples(suffix) "number of prefixes" times 
    suffix = np.tile(suffix, (numOfPrefixes,1))

    return np.core.char.add(prefix, suffix)
```

for the given inputs, this returns:

```
array([['blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike'],
   ['blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car'],
   ['brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike'],
   ['brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car']], 
  dtype='|S11')
```

Up to this point no loops were used. Since you asked the final output to be a list of tuples, `map` can be used to convert the above array to a list of tuples which runs a loop under the hood.

```
list(map(tuple,foo(prefix, suffix)))

[('blue dog', 'blue shoes', 'blue bike'),
 ('blue tree', 'blue cat', 'blue car'),
 ('brown dog', 'brown shoes', 'brown bike'),
 ('brown tree', 'brown cat', 'brown car')]
```